# problem in installing arcade package in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, package

i got the error while installing arcade package using pip install arcade command and it starts downloading and gets successful but got the error on installation describing error related to matadata.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLHhP.png)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
'c:\program files\python39\python.exe'
'C:\Users\kaush\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
'C:\Users\kaush\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpm02r2wt7'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLHhP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in python3.9 but it can easily work in previous version of python i.e python3.8.6 the following steps shows how to install arcade in python3.8.6:

1. Uninstall the latest version i.e python 3.9 or any other version.
2. Go to the path where the file is stored in your PC in my case the path is

> C:\Users\kaush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\

as you have to delete the folder python39 if you have uninstalled python3.9.

3. Go to the site by [arcade file](https://pypi.org/project/arcade/#files) and download the file.
4. Now download the python version3.8.6 from [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and install in you computer.
5. After getting installed open command prompt and type`pip install <arcade whl file full name you downloaded from the link in step 3> and press enter.`
6. Just wait for few minutes and it will get installed.

This process worked in window.